# geddy logger in production

Tags: node.js, geddy

Is there a way do define a location for geddy logger in production?

Similar with django where you could define different ways to log errors and warning like sending it to email for fatal errors and on s3 for standard errors?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue about this: https://github.com/mde/geddy/issues/387

We would love a pull request that lets people customize their logging strategy.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye on this.